# two dropdowns' selection javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have two visible one hidden dropdown and filter textbox works perfectly except checking flag if option already in selected list part, idea is you filter from hidden and see in visible dropdownlist, then select from visible and that goes to selected list. this part works until I added second for loop and flags which controls if option already in selected list then skip on filter and doesn't show in visible list which doesn't work.

If I delete between "FROM" to "HERE" comments works, but also  shows selecteds in visible list.

problem : frozen browser and visible list full of options like infinite.

```
function SearchList() {

    var listHidden = document.getElementById('<%= ddlStudentHidden.ClientID %>');
    var listVisible = document.getElementById('<%= ddlStudents.ClientID %>');
    var listSelected = document.getElementById('<%= ddlSelecteds.ClientID %>');
    var txtFind = document.getElementById('<%= txtFind.ClientID %>');

    $("#<%= ddlStudents.ClientID %>").find('option').remove();

    for (var i = 0; i < listHidden.options.length; i++) {
        if (listHidden.options[i].text.toLowerCase().match(txtFind.value.toLowerCase())) {
            /*FROM*/
            var flag = false;
            for (var i = 0; i < listSelected.options.length; i++) {
                if (!listSelected.options[i].text.toLowerCase().match(txtFind.value.toLowerCase())) {
                    flag = true;
                }
            }
            if (!flag) /*HERE*/
            $("#<%= ddlStudents.ClientID %>").append($('<option></option>').val(listHidden.options[i].value).html(listHidden.options[i].text));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo declare the variable i again in the inner loop which will override the the i in the outer loop. Rename the variable in the inner loop to something else except i.

Comment: I don't believe I did that simple mistake :)